# Saving data with autonumber primary key fields

Tags: c#, database, postgresql, primary-key, auto-increment

[image]

This is my DB in PostgreSQL. All the id fields are serial. The problem is when I try to save data from datagridviews when I have entered values in all 3 tables, its not saving and shows error: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

The code with what I am saving:

```
        adptDelivery.Update((DataTable)DGV_Delivery.DataSource);
        adptProduct.Update((DataTable)DGV_Product.DataSource);
        adptProduct_Delivery.Update((DataTable)DGV_Product_Delivery.DataSource);
```

Comment: That error sounds awfully vague, is it from the app?  If so, what does pgsql say in its logs while this is running?  PG should tell you which table, which pk constraint etc is causing the problem.

Comment: Which of those three statements causes the constraint violation? Are there any NOT NULL or UNIQUE constraints in play or just foreign keys?

Comment: @mu si adptProduct_Delivery.Update((DataTable)DGV_Product_Delivery.DataSource); this one it says :null value in column "id_product" violates not-null constraint

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna guess that you're trying to insert a unique number that's already been inserted by another process.  We need pseudo-code showing what you're doing and how you're doing it to really troubleshoot.

Comment: I am not inserting any unique number. I am inserting Product name and price, then I am inserting Delivery Supplier, an after this I am inserting that product and supplier in Product delivery.